# Nextjs with rollup for bundling

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, rollupjs

I'm trying to use rollup instead of webpack for bundling in nextjs.
Is there a way of doing it ? Views and suggestions on this topic will be very helpful.

Comment: Hello, Anish and welcome on stackoverflow!
Please, provide more info about the task you are solving and add code which you already tried. The more accurate your question is - the better answer you will get.

Comment: why do you want to use rollup instead will that make any improvements?

Comment: because rollup has lesser bundle size than webpack.

Comment: I have the same need as well! Looking for an answer here.

Comment: With webpack5 it's faster, although it would be nice to have a way for replace it with somethinganything